# CSS Alignment - Correcting Alignment of Floated Elements

Tags: css, css-float

I have a peculiar issue with CSS -- the 'VPS Plans' div and 'Features' div should be floated together and line up at the bottom. Unfortunately, unless I adjust the size of the Features div to 460px, it kicks down to the next line and I can't figure it out.

The page can be [seen here](http://dev002.rackcentral.com.au/virtual-servers/).

Thanks!

Comment: just to add some info, I checked on FF browser, and it seems to work fine, on Chrome, I could replicate the issue. Is that correct?

Comment: For me both elements are lined up in both Firefox and Chrome, however there are some strangly different margins. My suggestions: A) Validate your HTML. You have a UL instead a STRONG (which is completely invalid) inside a PRE (which makes no sense. Why a PRE?). B) Stop using hard-coded pixel sizes. Actually stop thinking in pixels. You are using **responsive** Bootstrap, so it makes absolutely no sense to use fixed pixel widths.

Answer (score -1):

Everything is looks good, you need to add `display: inline-table;` for below CSS.

> The element will displayed as an inline-level table

```
ul.vt li.vt-line-header {
display: inline-table;  //----Add this to your CSS
}
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: @Anon On checking OP's site it seems, `inline-block` left some space between VPS Plans' div and 'Features' div.  You know sometimes CSS play around like this. We may think but sometimes it acts differently due to some other CSS conflict(may be).  Hope you understand.